# nodejs express recursive routing fails (404)

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, express

I started a new node project and wanted to dynamically add routes. I have done that before, but never went more into depth than one level of folders.
For this purpose, I came up with a recursive function to add the routes und traverse through possible subfolders. The function is called in my app.js. The project folder looks like this:

```
app.js
routes/
    index.js
    users.js
    api/
        foo.js
        test/
            bar.js
```

The definition and call of the function in app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

// Works
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);


// 404
getRoutes('routes');

function getRoutes(dir, cur) {
    if(cur === undefined) {
        cur = '/';
    }
    routes = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));
    routes.forEach( function (file) {

        fs.stat(dir + "/" + file, function (err, stats) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            else if (stats.isFile()) {
                var routeFilePath = "./" + path.join(dir, file);
                var route = path.join(cur, file.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""))+'/';
                if(file == 'index.js') {
                    route = cur;
                }
                console.log(route, "defined in:", routeFilePath);

                var routeFile = require(routeFilePath);
                app.use(route, routeFile);
            }
            else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                getRoutes(path.join(dir, file), path.join(cur, file));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Please notice, that the direct call of `app.use()` works.
Does anyone see the error?

The Output of `console.log(route, "defined in:", routeFilePath);`:

```
/ defined in: ./routes/index.js
/users/ defined in: ./routes/users.js
/api/foo/ defined in: ./routes/api/foo.js
/api/test/bar/ defined in: ./routes/api/test/bar.js
```

looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fs.stats() is async. The routes have to be defined synchronously like:

```
function getRoutes(dir, cur) {
    if(cur === undefined) {
        cur = '/';
    }
    routes = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));
    routes.forEach( function (file) {

        var stats = fs.statSync(dir + "/" + file);
        if (stats.isFile()) {
            var routeFilePath = "./" + path.join(dir, file);
            var route = path.join(cur, file.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""))+'/';
            if(file == 'index.js') {
                route = cur;
            }
            console.log(route, "defined in:", routeFilePath);

            var routeFile = require(routeFilePath.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, ""));
            console.log(routeFile);
            app.use(route, routeFile);
        }
        else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            getRoutes(path.join(dir, file), path.join(cur, file));
        }

    });
}
```